# (Sockets) Better to use thread or loop for receiving data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking

Currently I'm developing a server application where multiple user are able to join. So, I'd like to recv data of any user. There are two ways for solving this problem:

1. using threads for any single user which receives data
2. using one thread where an iterator receives data of any user that was saved in a list.

```
    int singleUserThread(SOCKET client) {
    recv(...);
    }
```

or

```
    int oneThread() {
        std::vector clientList;

        for(std::vector::iterator it = clientList.begin();
                it != clientList.end(); it++) {
            recv(*it ...);
        }

    }
```

Which way should I use? Which is more efficient?